# Magento2 order is not created after payment

Tags: magento2, payment

I have a weird problem. Order seem not properly created after payment successfully. Order is expected to show in **Sales -> Orders** but it's not. I can find that missing order from customer account in frontend and **Sales -> Transactions**. Could anyone know what's the reason of this.

I also check paypal buyer and merchant account to ensure transaction is actually made. paypal IPN is also good. Does anyone have the same issue?

thanks in advance.

**additional question:**

I have a remote production and local development magento. Two days ago I upgraded my local magento via composer and then push it to my production site. And then I run the **setup:upgrade** in production. It seems working fine. But not sure if this a common practice to upgrade or will it causes implicit issue just like this one?

Comment: Please, specify version of Magento and attach debug, exception and apache logs

Comment: Hi Jones, there is no error. Magento 2.0.7 and Php 7.0.7

Comment: Have you found the solution or root cause for this issue? How did you solve it?

Answer (score 1):

Finally after hours checking around, I found the culprit to be **Stores -> Configuration -> Developer -> Grid Settings -> Asynchronous indexing**.

Setting it back to **Disable** solve my issue.

It's a pity that the current official document (PDF) has not mentioned what Asynchnornous indexing is.

Comment: By disabling this setting, won't this kind of issues occur again?

Comment: How the heck does changing Developer settings affect your production deployment?

Comment: @SpencerWilliams It only shows if it's in developer mode but the option affects the way that the grid is updated in any mode. It's hidden in production so the common user like your client or so don't change it easily I guess. In terms of the asynchronous I think it works with the cron that is supposed to run every minute and update the grid if it's off it will upload when the order is created causing a bigger load on server. Not sure 100% of this but for my experience it was what I understood, so try checking if the cron is running fine